# Find duplicates in different rows

Tags: r, duplicates, panel-data

I have a data frame such this:

```
   Country1 Country2    year
          A   B         1993
          A   B         1994
          A   C         1993
          A   C         1994
          B   A         1993
          B   A         1994
          B   C         1993 
          B   C         1994
```

I need to get rid off all the rows with duplications in both column one and two together.

I wrote my own function, but it works too slow on a large dataset. Is there a more effective way?

Comment: Surely a duplicate. Search on "[r] duplicated data.frame".

Comment: How is your output required different from `unique` or `duplicated`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
 Country1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
 Country2 <- c("B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C")        
 year <- c("1993", "1994", "1993", "1994", "1993", "1994", "1993", "1994")
 dat <- data.frame(
    Country1,
    Country2,
    year
    )

 dat <- dat[ !duplicated( dat[ ,c(1, 2)]), ]
 dat

   Country1 Country2 year
 1        A        B 1993
 3        A        C 1993
 5        B        A 1993
 7        B        C 1993
```

Comment: My apologies, I didnt make clear explanation. I need the data frame look like this:    `CountryA <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B")                                                      CountryB <- c("B","B","C","C","C","C")                                                            year <- c(1993,1994,1993,1994,1993,1994) df <- data.frame(CountryA,CountryB,year) print(df)`                                       The data are on bilateral trade. Thus, the repetition of pairs of countries are extra and i need to get rid off it. Thanks for helping!